# Nested ViewPager with overscroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager, overscroll

I have one `ViewPager` inside another `ViewPager`. Also, I don't want the child `ViewPager` to change the position of the parent `ViewPager`.

So, I implemented my own ViewPager with the following overridden method:

```
@Override
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {

    if(v != this && v instanceof ViewPager {

        return true;
    }
    return super.canScroll(v, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
}
```

This works perfectly.

Now, I want to achieve the native over-scroll edge effect on the child `ViewPager` when the `ViewPager` reaches the last element.

The problem is that I have overridden the `canScroll()` method to return true, so the edge-effect on over scroll gets disabled. Is there any way to achieve this?